# Approximation of ellipse with circles - no idea?

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $E$ be the ellipse , such that for $a,b>0$
>   $$E=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R : \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\}$$
>
> Find the equation of the [osculating circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OsculatingCircle.html) at $(x,y)\in E.$

I just wanted to ask , if someone can tell me , what I have to do, which formula I shall use or anything else.

I've calculated the curvature $\kappa(t)$ and know that for a circle $$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$$

$r^2=\frac{1}{\kappa^2}$

And for $a=b=r$ we get the circle formula from the ellipse formula.

Shall I just put $x_0=y_0=0$ and that's it ? 
I guess it's not.

Comment: Most likely it means find the osculating circle at that point in the curve. The radius $r$ is the inverse of the curvature, and the center is along the normal, a distance $r$ from the point in the curve. It is probably easier to do with the ellipse in parametric form: $x=a\cos(t),\;y=b\sin(t)$.

Comment: Maybe of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340241/centers-of-the-osculating-circles-along-an-ellipse

Answer (score 1):

At a point $\mathbf{P} = (h,k)$ on the ellipse, the tangent line has equation 
$$
\frac{hx}{a^2} + \frac{ky}{b^2} = 1
$$
The normal to this line is in the direction of the vector 
$$
\mathbf{N} = \left( \frac{h}{a^2} , \frac{k}{b^2} \right)
$$
Let $\mathbf{U}$ be the unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{N}$ pointing towards the interior of the ellipse, and let $\rho$ be the radius of curvature at $\mathbf{P}$ (which you say you have calculated). Then the osculating circle at $\mathbf{P}$ has its center at $\mathbf{P} +\rho\mathbf{U}$ and has radius $\rho$. From this information, I expect you can get the equation of this circle.